# SG3525 PWM duty cycle problem

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle

I'm struggling to increase duty cycle in the controller. I'm using SG3525 on control PCB. As can be seen below, R12,R22 and C12 components are selected for 58kHz frequency. 
[image: circuit]
However, I can't get duty cycle more than 45%. Typical duty cycle is given 47% in datasheet. Does the max. duty cycle limited by frequency?

Comment: You can get a higher duty cycle at the vc pin, but it only sinks current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasheet only guarantee 45 % duty cycle. You should not expect more.

[image]